# denied specific script of java script from a head use selenium c# js

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium

we're having one issue we wanna denied  specific script js from our  server , which that mean not calling that specific script js. for exemple this script :  if we removed this link , the whole code of javascript doen't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="jQuery.js"></script>

    <title>index</title>
</head>
<body onload=" ed()">
    <h1 id='h1'>Hello World</h1>
    <script >
        function ed()
        {$('#h1').text('Hello Noureddine'); }
    </script>
</body>
```

as an  result `Hello World`

Comment: Can you explain more what you mean by "we wanna denied specific script js from our server?" Does that mean you do not want one of the scripts to run? And if so, which script do you want to skip?

Comment: I want to cancel the script `Jquery.js`

Comment: I'm confused how this is a Selenium question as written.

Comment: The scripts executed by Selenium may have their own scope.... meaning anything you define is only available during that executeScript call.  So basically you could re-write pieces of the DOM to take out the text of "Hello Noureddine", but you couldn't prevent it from being created.  (That code has already run...)  For things like event handlers you could remove them, but not "onload".  The page has already loaded. (You can tell Selenium not to wait for a pageload, but I don't think you can tell the browser to execute your script before a page ready state.)